# Get taxonomy field value in forum-list.html.twig

Tags: theming, nodes, 9

I am customizing the appearance of the forums.

I added all my forums and container. Additionally, I added a custom taxonomy field I need to show for each forum category.

> [image: screenshot]

How can I show the custom taxonomy field in forum-list.html.twig?

I know how to show content fields from nodes in node.html.twig, but how do I show custom taxonomy fields in forum-list.html.twig?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague.

I suggest setting up xdebug (https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/development-tools/xdebug-debugger) then using the function `devel_breakpoint()` to be able to see how to reach the values/fields of your entity.

If your taxonomy is attached to your topic, I'm assuming that the solution will be something like `forum.taxonomy_field.value`.

If your taxonomy is not attached to your topic, you should have a look to preprocess your topic to add the missing data by using `template_preprocess_forum_list()`   I guess?

Here is the list of all preprocess hook, maybe another one with forum might do the trick: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/implementations/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x